# What's the Difference between Session.Add("key",value) and Session["key"] = value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

Can somebody please explain to me the difference between:

`Session.Add("name",txtName.text);` and `Session["name"] = txtName.text;`

It was an interview question and I answered that both store data in `key = "Value"` format like `Dictionary` class in C#.

Am I right, or is there any difference?

Comment: I'm sure there's some nice msdn documentation regarding this. Perhaps you could research it yourself and be better prepared for the next interview.

Comment: That is a *terrible* interview question.

Comment: @EricLippert, I completely agree. Process of hiring a developer is highly broken at most organizations.

Comment: @EricLippert If nothing else, it throws up flags for inexperienced developers who may not know the two are identical. IMO most web devs should know this. But in general yes it's a weak question.

Comment: @EricLippert Off-topic and years later...  I was once asked to convert a decimal number into hexidecimal during an interview.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Looking at the code for `HttpSessionState` shows us that they are in fact the same.

```
public sealed class HttpSessionState : ICollection, IEnumerable
{
    private IHttpSessionState _container;
...
    public void Add(string name, object value)
    {
        this._container[name] = value;
    }

    public object this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            return this._container[name];
        }
        set
        {
            this._container[name] = value;
        }
    }
...
}
```

As for them both

> Storing data in `key = "Value"` format like `Dictionary` class in C#.

They actually store the result in an `IHttpSessionState` object.

Comment: This is a great answer because it shows in code exactly why the two functions are equivalent which helps to internalize the concept. I like the note in another Comment by @matthew about Dictionary, because I've been thinking all along that we were using a Dictionary or other hash table in session state, and frankly I've always done the silly dance to check to see if a value already existed before either adding or modifying based on that.

Comment: That is not the same because: When the __key__ exist the __value__ is **_update_** but if the __key__ __doesn't__ exist they **_create_** with the __value__, if like __**SaveOrUpdate**__ method.

Answer (score 13):

The two code snippets you posted are one and the same in functionality. Both update (or create if it doesn't exist) a certain `Session` object defined by the key.

`Session.Add("name",txtName.text);`

is the same as:

`Session["name"] = txtName.text;`

The first is `method-based,` where the second is string `indexer-based`.

Both overwrite the previous value held by the key.

Comment: In contrast to a `Dictionary`, if you try and `Add` to a dictionary twice with the same key, it will throw an exception.  The indexer of a `Dictionary` works similarly to the `Session` object (it will either add or update, and will not throw an exception).

Comment: @Mathew - Thanks for the extra note